# Uniswap and other exchange. How the bots calculate the amount to buy

Tags: web3js, ether, uniswap, math

Met with such a problem that I can not calculate the amount to buy in front of the user, so that his transaction would be successful. All of the formulas I used to do this produced to the point that my purchase amount was more than required and because of this, the user's transaction that was after mine ended up failing.

But not long ago noticed here is such a bot, which is very personally selects this amount, could someone share a formula for calculating or at least the direction in which to look. Providing links to bscscan below.

User purchase: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x441e40b8a31b3a9876443d7132b08086dd3f71d31154000e9325cc2ed149f023

Bot purchase: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x32993b08bdbc80b07fdaa63b5ea8c37e8e7ee8f38360728848dfff3059bbb118

As you can see the transactions were made in one block, and the bot picked up, a very accurate amount to buy.

The minimum the user wanted to get was: 23418.444644965093

The user actually received: 23418.444644965095902035

I would be glad and grateful for any help.

Comment: How are you calculating the expected output? Did you use `getAmountOut`?

Comment: Yes im use getAmountOut